# custom event is undefined in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript

We used Custom Event in Javascript, it works fine in Chrome and firefox. But in Internet Explorer it is showing error 'Custom event is undefined'.

I am using Internet Explorer 8.

please anyone suggest how to correct the code for IE ?

Answer (score 0):

You should get the `event` that way:

```
event = event || window.event;
```

Since I.E doesn't pass it along as a parameter, but uses a global variable.